# Canvas in table cell doesn't work on Firefox

Tags: firefox, canvas, html-table

I' try to drawing canvas using example2 taken from http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/html5-canvas-painting/. It works on Firefox 8.0.1 and Opera 11.52.

Then I modified the code put the canvas into a table cell and stop working.
I tried to put canvas outside the table and absolute positioned the canvas on a cell table still doesn't work.
The above problem happened only on Firefox, running well on Opera.

Here's the code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en"><head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Sign-In</title>
    <style type="text/css"><!--
      #imageView { border: 1px solid #000; }
    --></style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p>Please fill in name and id card no. Then sign-in on provided box</p>
    <table>
    <tr><td>Full Name</td><td><input name="name"><td>   </tr>
    <tr><td>ID Card No</td><td><input name="idcard"><td>    </tr>
    <tr><td>Signature</td><td>
    <div id="container">
      <canvas id="imageView" width="200" height="100">      </canvas>
    </div>
    </td>   </tr>
</table>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/html5-canvas-painting/example2.js"></script>
</body></html>
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, here is your code in jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/7PRDq/

The problem is almost certainly the mouse handling code giving a bad X,Y in Firefox. If you try to draw a signature in the upper-left corner of the box you'll see that it is drawing with an incorrect offset.

If you make the canvas 2000x1000 instead of 200x100 you'll see the problem much more clearly!

You'll need to find more modern mouse code for FireFox.

Comment: It's weird, i checked on jsfiddle, it's work though given unexpected result on Firefox. on my localhost, can't see any things on the same size. when i made the canvas size to 500x500, just like on jsfiddle.
anyway, it's gave me a clue. thank you @simon-sarris